# Signification de « où qu'œil fût »

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Je suis récemment tombé sur le pangramme « Dès Noël, à Aÿ giboyeux où qu'œil fût, j'ai rêvé ça : Ésaü, aîné haï, ôtez de l'æthuse ce kiwi pâmé » qui utilise les 42 caractères existant en français. Après quelques recherches, je n'arrive pas à trouver le sens de  « où qu'œil fût ». Quel est-il ?

Comment: Amusant, c'est presque la seule chose que j'ai comprise du texte :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Quel que soit l'endroit où l'œil se pose (où l'on regarde).

Answer (score 1):

> où qu'œil fût

can be literally translated to "wherever an eye was", and is a dated way to say "everywhere".